Shopify - Determine if a Collection is actively used
Over the years we have created MANY smart collections.  As we evolved and found better ways to handle situations, many of these collection have become irrelevant.
Is there a way to see if a collection is 'Active', i.e. used as a menu item or referenced from a product page (or a hidden last accessed date)?

Please provide more context. For instance, how do you want to determine if a collection is "Active" or not, through API or using liquid? And please share what you tried on your end, too.

I wish to know if a collection is used in any menu items, but sadly Shopify doesn't have a way to export (or import) your menu structure.  If we have a collection that is no longer referenced on our site (with the exception of 'All Collections') we could delete that collection without consequences.
We tried "Matrixify", and I've tried looking into liquid, but couldn't find a path to a solution.  I don't have access to the API.
